# Largest-area shape with diameter 1?

Tags: geometry, optimization, area, extremal-combinatorics

Define the diameter of a shape as the greatest distance between any two of its points.  What diameter 1 shape has the greatest area?

Is it the circle?

I've been looking for the [biggest little polyhedron](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BiggestLittlePolyhedron/) for awhile, and looked at [biggest little polygon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BiggestLittlePolygon.html) again. A paper by [Henrion and Messine](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.4456.pdf) extended results to the 16-gon.  The trend shows that the best area is chaotic, with the optimal 14-gon having a better improvement over the regular 14-gon by a factor higher than shown in the 8, 10, and 12 gons.

[image: optimal decagon]

If the trend continues, there may be a unit [thrackle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrackle) that generates a 50-gon to 90-gon of diameter 1 with a total area greater than a circle of diameter 1.

It might be possible faster than that, by using [Reuleaux polygon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReuleauxPolygon.html) methods.

What diameter-1 shape has the greatest area? Diameter 1 polygons that won't fit in a diameter 1 circle are easy to find, but is there one with an outside area that exceeds the uncovered area?

[image: triangle and circle]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it is the circle by the following reasoning. I'm not totally sure about this though, so if there is an error hopefully someone can correct me.

The shape of maximal area must be bounded by a [curve of constant width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width) (with the diameter being the width), since any curve of varying width could be expanded in the directions where the width is deficient, increasing the area while keeping the diameter the same.

Now by [Barbier's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbier's_theorem), the perimeter of any curve of constant width $w$ is just $\pi w$, regardless of the shape. Thus all shapes that can be candidates for optimality must have the same perimeter.

But by the [isoperimetric inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality), a circle is the curve enclosing maximal area among all shapes with a given perimeter. Thus the circle encloses the maximal area among all shapes with a given diameter.

Comment: Candidate shape -> curve of constant width -> Barbier's theorem -> isoperimetric inequality.  That's a very clever way of thinking about it.  It wouldn't apply to the 3D case.

Comment: It's a good idea, but as written I would consider it to have quite large gaps. You claim that it "could be expanded ..." without proof. And it is non-trivial. I advise you to try **precisely** specifying the expansion, and **rigorously** proving that the diameter does not increase, and you should see what I mean.

Comment: In fact, "any curve of varying width could be expanded in the directions where the width is deficient" is pretty unclear how to prove: consider a very thin rectangle (essentially a line) of dimension 1 by epsilon. The supporting lines parallel to long edges of the rectangle enclose diameter epsilon. The basic way to expand this is to add a perpendicular line of length 1-epsilon. To preserve diameter 1 you need to bisect the two lines. But it's not clear how to do this in general, as the point of this problem is there is no "center bisection point" for an arbitrary shape.

Answer (score 5):

The isodiametric inequality states $V(C) \le \left(\frac{\operatorname{diam}(C)}{2}\right)^n V(B_2^n)$ for any bounded set $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. This means that a ball of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ has the biggest volume of all shapes with diameter at most $1$.

A prove can be found in Gruber's book about convex geometry. Wlog you can assume $C$ to be convex and compact. It boils down to applying successive Steiner-symmetrizations with respect to the coordinate hyperplanes to $C$. The result is a convex body $D$ that has the same volume as $C$, the diameter of $D$ is at most the diameter of $C$ and $D$ is symmetric with respect to the origin. The last part implies that $D$ is a subset of  $\frac{\operatorname{diam}(D)}{2} B_2^n$.

Comment: [Useful link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/749528/isoperimetric-inequality-isodiametric-inequality-hyperplane-conjecture-what).  I like your answer for the 3D case.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a convex and compact set containing any bounded set with the same diameter. For any convex body there exists successive Steiner-symmetrizations that converge to a ball. Those symmetrizations preserve volume without increasing diameter. So the ball is an answer in any dimensions. In two dimensions you can find polygon of odd order approximating arbitarily well a given compact and convex set. A result of Reinhardt shows that the maximal area polygones of odd order are regular $n$-gons. So the answer is the disk.