# For convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of unit diameter, is the maximum boundary attained by the sphere?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

If we have a set of points in the plane of diameter 1, the perimeter of its convex hull is at most $\pi$; this is attained by the shapes of constant width (circle, Releaux triangle, etc). See [Barbier's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbier%27s_theorem).

(I can find this fact mentioned without citation in Gallego and Solanes, [*Perimeter, diameter, and area of convex sets in the hyperbolic plane*](https://silo.tips/download/perimeter-diameter-and-area-of-convex-sets-in-the-hyperbolic-plane), but have not located a proof; direction to such would be appreciated. [This math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604957/largest-area-shape-with-diameter-1) asks the same question, though I'm not sure the accepted answer's argument is fully rigorous.)

I'm curious if this result extends to higher dimensions - for instance, among convex solids of diameter $1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, is the surface area of the solid at most $\pi$?

Interestingly, it seems that in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the solids of constant width do *not* all attain the same value: [this source](https://www.swisseduc.ch/mathematik/geometrie/gleichdick/docs/meissner_mysterious%20_bodies.pdf) suggests that Meissner bodies of unit diameter have a surface area of only $2.934$. It also notes that among solids of a fixed constant width, volume and surface area are monotonically increasing in each other, so the constant-width surface of maxmimal volume will also be that of maximal surface area. (I believe this is the sphere, but I don't know if this has been proven beyond the case of solids of revolution of constant width.)

This disparity suggests to me that proof techniques used in the two-dimensional case may not generalize, and that there is some chance that non-spherical shapes (perhaps other solids of constant width?) have higher surface area. The [isoperimetric inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality) implies that any shape of unit diameter with higher volume than a ball would serve as such a counterexample, but I believe no such shapes exist.

Comment: Found this question answered elsewhere! This follows from the isodiametric inequality, as described at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/754758.