# Circle has smallest shadow to area ratio

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry

I believe and would like to show that for an arbitrary two-dimensional geometrical figure, the average (with respect to rotation) one-dimensional shadow that it casts is larger than the shadow of a circle of the same area.

Just to clarify:

Let us define the figure as a set of points in a (x,y) coordinate system. 
We confine the problem to closed and bounded sets, and it is easily seen that any non-convex set has a convex equivalent with the same shadow and larger area, so we only need to consider convex sets.

The shadow with respect to a parallel vertical light source is the largest x-value in the set minus the smallest x-value in the set.
We now calculate the shadow for all rotations of the figure, and average the shadow as a function of the angle with uniform weight to all angles.

For example, the shadow of a circle is its diameter, and the shadow of a rod with length $l$ is $l \sin \phi$, where $\phi$ is the angle between the rod and the y-axis.

Comment: You really want your definition of "figure" to include "closed and bounded". This ensures, for instance, that there _exists_ a largest $x$-value. And to ensure that a figure has a well-defined area, you can stipulate that it be convex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "for an arbitrary two-dimensional geometrical figure, the average (with respect to rotation) one-dimensional shadow that it casts is larger than the shadow of a circle of the same area"

This is a consequence of **Urysohn's inequality**, which states that 
among all convex bodies in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a fixed volume, a Euclidean [n-ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#n-ball) has minimal mean width. More precisely:

> If $A$ is a convex body in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then
>   $$\frac{\text{vol}(A)}{\bar{w}(A)^n} \le \frac{\text{vol}(B)}{\bar{w}(B)^n}$$
>   where $B$ denotes the Euclidean unit $n$-ball and $\bar{w}(\cdot)$ denotes the *mean width*.

Given a convex body $A\subset\mathbb R^n$ and a direction $v\in\mathcal{S}^{n-1}$, the *width* $w(A, v)$ is defined as the Euclidean distance between two supporting hyperplanes of $A$ in the directions $v$ and $-v$:

[image]

The *mean width* of $A$ is defined as

$$\bar{w}(A) = \int_{\mathcal{S}^{n-1}}w(A, v)\,\sigma(dv)
$$

where $\sigma$ is the rotationally invariant probability measure on the unit sphere [$\mathcal S^{n-1}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere).

Since $\bar{w}(B) = 2$ and $\text{vol}(B) = \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2} + 1)}$, the inequality can be written
$$\bar{w}(A)^n \ge \left( \frac{2^n\ \Gamma(\frac{n}{2} + 1)}{\pi^{n/2}}   \right)\ \text{vol}(A)
$$
with equality holding iff $A$ is a ball.

In the present case, $n=2$:
$$\bar{w}(A)^2 \ge \left(\frac{4}{\pi}\right)\text{area}(A)
$$
with equality iff $A$ is circular, in which case we have $\bar{w}(A)^2 = \left(\frac{4}{\pi}\right)\pi R^2 = (2R)^2 $ for a circular ball of radius $R$. In this case, the width is what you call the "shadow", and the integral defining the mean width reduces to the average you describe (with the direction $v$ rotating, instead of rotating the figure).

Hence, among all planar convex figures with a given area, a circular disk has the minimal mean width.

**NB**: Proofs of Urysohn's inequality can be found on p. 12 ff. of *Geometry of Isotropic Convex Bodies* by Silouanos Brazitikos, Apostolos Giannopoulos, Petros Valettas, Beatrice-Helen Vritsiou (which can be previewed online), and also as sketched in [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/754758/16397).